# How to address arbitray leds (WS2812B) in an already defined leds array?

Tags: arduino-uno, ws2812

I want to address the first and last three pixels of a 9 pixel strip and apply a gradient to them using FastLED.  I can successfully address them but the colors displayed are not correct.  Is there something I'm overlooking or misunderstand about the way FastLED works?

```
#include <FastLED.h>

// the whole strip
#define NUM_LEDS 9

#define LED_PIN 6

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

// Define the indexes of the first and last 3 indexes of a 9 pixel strip
int customLeds[6] = {0,1,2,6,7,8};

// My Palette
DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE (heatmap) {
  0, 255, 0, 0,      // Red
  128, 0, 255, 0,    // Green
  255, 0, 0, 255     // Blue
};

CRGBPalette16 myPalette1 = heatmap;

void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(20);
}

void loop() {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(customLeds)); i++) {
   // Each i led get the correct color given their place in the array  - 0, 42.5, 85, 127.5, 170, 212.5, 255
    leds[customLeds[i]] = ColorFromPalette(myPalette1, (i * (255 / sizeof(customLeds))), 255, LINEARBLEND); 
  }
  
  FastLED.show();

}
```

Comment: Sizeof doesn't give the number of elements but the amount of memory used by the array ..

Comment: what does this mean? ... `colors displayed are not correct`

Comment: The colors of the pixels needs to follow the pallete but while they are colors from the pallete they are right..they're all over the gradient and not folowing linearly.

Comment: I realized my problem...this:(i * (255 / sizeof(customLeds)) - doesn't work because the two arrays are of different lengths! I'm homing in on a solution.

Comment: Please replace `sizeof(customLeds)` with `sizeof(customLeds)/sizeof(customLeds[0])` to actually get the numbers of elements in the array instead of the number of bytes

Comment: Yes, a slightly more elegant solution.  I just hard coded the total for ease of use.  Later in the project I plan to use this. But given my solution below, that method become moot as I use a boolean array of the total length.  Hence my use of the hard coded total and the increment variable. Thanks @chrisl

Answer (score 1):

So here is the answer I came up with:

```
#include <FastLED.h>

// the whole strip
#define NUM_LEDS 9

#define LED_PIN 6

CRGB leds[NUM_LEDS];

// Define the indexes of the first and last 3 indexes of a 9 pixel strip
bool customLeds[9] = {1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
int customLeds_num = 6;


// My Palette
DEFINE_GRADIENT_PALETTE (heatmap) {
  0, 255, 0, 0,      // Red
  128, 0, 255, 0,    // Green
  255, 0, 0, 255     // Blue
};

CRGBPalette16 myPalette1 = heatmap;


void setup() {
  FastLED.addLeds<WS2812B, LED_PIN, GRB>(leds, NUM_LEDS);
  FastLED.setBrightness(5);

}

void loop() {

  FastLED.clear();

  //  Keep track of how many leds have been lit
  int customLedIndex1 = 0;
  

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_LEDS; i++) {
    // Each i led get the correct color given their place in the array  - 0, 42.5, 85, 127.5, 170, 212.5, 255

    //lights a specific pixel only if it's in the customLeds truth table
    if (customLeds[i]) {
      // works out where on the gradient a specific pixel is
      leds[i] = ColorFromPalette(myPalette1, (customLedIndex1 * (255 / 5)), 255, LINEARBLEND);

      //increments the index for the next pixels value on the gradient
      customLedIndex1++;

    }

  }

  FastLED.show();
  
  customLedIndex1 = 0;

}
```

The solution involved using a boolean array that indicates which leds needed to be on (true / 1) and which off (false / 0) and then create a separate index (customLedIndex) which counted how many of the leds where lit so they could receive the correct color corresponding to their 'place' in the palette